# Azure Export ARM Template: Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies cannot be exported yet and is not included in the template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

We are exporting our Azure Key vault to a ARM template. However we get a warning that says:

> Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies cannot be exported yet and is
> not included in the template. See error details.

[image]

Raw Error:

```
{
  "code": "ExportTemplateCompletedWithErrors",
  "message": "Export template operation completed with errors. Some resources were not exported. Please see details for more information.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "ExportTemplateProviderError",
      "target": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "message": "Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies'. Resources of this type will not be exported."
    }
  ]
}
```

The weird thing is that in the template there is a complete section of `accessPolicies` that match our current settings under the tab `Access policies`. Exactly what is not exported?

[image]

Comment: Any other concern about this issue?

Comment: @JoyWang Yes - why is the warning present if access policies are exported?

Comment: Not sure, you may need to send a support ticket to MSFT. All I can tell you is the template does not affect the use.

Comment: @JoyWang What do you mean by the template does not affect the use. The reason for exporting templates is to use them to create resources. The template is ***all of what's being used.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a new Key Vault and then used `Download a template for automation`. No warnings and everything worked as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can also reproduce your issue, not sure what caused this.

Per my test, if you click the `Download` button to export the template, you will find the template is completely correct, including the `accessPolicies`.

[image]

[image]

Also, I test to use this exported template to deploy a new keyvault, all work fine, including the `accessPolicies`.

[image]

So if you want to export the template and use it, don't care about the issue, feel free to do that.